# AWS ElasticBeanstalk (Python) Environment Variables disappear after being set

Tags: environment-variables, amazon-web-services

So I am experiencing a funny problem.

I am using ElasticBeanstalk on AWS, and I have several Applications initialized along with their corresponding Environments.

In the past I have been able to set environment variables by clicking on "Configuration" (Under the Dashboard link), and then clicking on "modify" on the first option - Software.

The Modify Software tab has a section called Container options where you can set the WSGIPath, NumProcesses, NumThreads. At the bottom of the page there is a section for setting Environment Properties in a Name|Value format.

Now the funny part: For some reason, every time I add a new environment variable and click "Save", the new value disappears if I refresh the page. Basically I cannot add any new environment variables.  The pre-existing variables I have are unaffected.

Does anyone know what on earth could be causing this?

I have recently set up a new environment using python 3.6 (an upgrade from python 2.7). But I am experiencing the same problem on some of my older Python 2.7 environments as well.  This is very annoying!!

Thank you for reading.

[EBS Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb4OQ.png)
[Pic of Add Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHbyf.png)

EDIT: This appears to be caused by a bug in the New Elastic Beanstalk Interface (that I was unknowingly opted-into) where you literally cannot save any changes you have made to your settings.